# What's the best strategy to update from 32bit to 64bit installation?

Tags: install4j

What is the recommended way to update from a 32bit installation up to a 64bit installation? In particular when the update should be done automatically. My initial idea was to change only the bundled jre, but this wouldn't fit the bitness of the installer itself. Another way I thought would work is to load the response file of the previous installation, deinstall it and using the variables for the installation of the current application. But this seems also not to work. When I tried to update to the current 64bit application silently I get the following logfile entries and the installation abort caused by missing installation variables:

```
...
sun.cpu.isalist=amd64
[INFO] bitness BIT32 from C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp is not compatible
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.RequestPrivilegesAction [ID 13]: Execute action
...
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.LoadResponseFileAction [ID 5]: Execute action
   Property file: null
   Property excludedVariables: null
   Property overwriteStrategy: Do not overwrite command line
   Property registerForResponseFile: true
   Property rollbackSupported: true
   Response file C:\Program Files\MyApp\.install4j\response.varfile does not exist
   Execute action successful after 0 ms
....
```

So what's the best practice way to handle such an update scenario?

Comment: Probably "C:\Program Files\MyApp" is not the previous installation directory. The idea about finding the previous installation directory with the application registry should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you are gonna have to uninstall 32-bit and install the 64-bit version

Comment: I am afraid too and this would be okay when the response file could be loaded before deinstallation so the values could be used for the installation of the current version.